# Add ics file to outlook 2011 (Mac) as new calendar

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar

I've created an `.ics` file with multiple events that I would like to add to Outlook as a new calendar (so I can easily remove it).  If I double click the `.ics` file, the events get added to my current calendar (not a new one).  I can't find a menu item to add or import a calendar either.

I think I'm missing something obvious.  Any ideas?

Outlook 2011 for Mac

Thanks

Comment: I want to do just reverse of this, Could you please help to get rid out of this.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add a new calendar (sometimes called a folder) to the calendar section of Outlook and then DRAG the `.ics` file to the Outlook calendar window (with the new calendar selected), the `.ics` file is added to that calendar instead of the default calendar.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in first comment, I didnt add a new Calender/Folder. Instead

1. Click the "Calendar" section in outlook.
2. Drag and drop your ics file directly into Calendar.

that will do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use X-WR-CALNAME in your .ics file to choose which calendar to import into.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer